# bash: force function to call alias

Tags: bash, alias

I have a function that I use in place of `cd`, and I have `cd` aliased to call it.  My question is, is it possible to force all functions and scripts to call my `cd_func` through the alias, rather than calling `cd` directly.

Here's an example using `ls`, because it's simpler:

**.myfile**:

```
ls_func(){
    echo "function called"
    dir
}
alias ls=ls_func
```

**.notmyfile**

```
ls_func2(){
    ls
}
```

It's important to note that `.notmyfile` is sourced before `.myfile` is.  What I want is to force `ls_func2` to call `ls_func` instead of `ls` directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sourcing in bash overwrites functions which are the same, so the source order in this case does not matter (until you call a function before the related function is loaded.

To make this work add this to the top of your script:

```
shopt -s expand_aliases
```

This command is used to make aliasing work in non-interactive scripts.

Comment: at the top of the `cd_func` or the top of the entire source file?

Comment: Best is at top of the file, but just before creating the alias should also be sufficient.

Comment: So I'm having an issue.  I have the command at the top of the sourcefile.  When I load a new terminal, `ls_func2` does not call `ls_func` (i.e. it does not go through the alias).  I have to manually source my `.bash_profile` in order to get it to work.

Comment: Add your .bash_profile to the question so that a relation can be found.